# 1054 - Unknown column 'apa_calda' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1054

I keep getting the error `1054 - Unknown column 'apa_calda' in 'where clause'` in MySQL. Here is the query:

```
SELECT user_id FROM `detalii_contor` WHERE tip_contor=apa_calda
```

I want to use this query in a PHP file but it doesn't give any results. So I tried to write it in the SQL command prompt.
Here is what I tried in the PHP file:

```
$Q = "SELECT id_contor, den_contor FROM detalii_contor WHERE tip_contor='".$contor."'";

$Q = "SELECT id_contor, den_contor FROM detalii_contor WHERE tip_contor='$contor'";
```

even without `""` or without `''`.

I wanted to get `$contor` from a form. I also tried with `$_POST['util']` and `{$_POST['util']}`. I've also tried to set `$contor` the value I need, but no result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Field value should be in quotes.
    `SELECT user_id FROM detalii_contor WHERE tip_contor='apa_calda'`

By the way, you should always escape everything that comes from users. For example,

`$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "db");

 $contor = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['util'] );

 $result = $mysqli->query(SELECT id_contor, den_contor FROM detalii_contor WHERE tip_contor='$contor'");`

Comment: the first line i wrote was in mysql prompt, where i get the error.

in php i don't get any results or errors.

Comment: When you run the first line on mysql prompt, you got an error because you didn't use quotes. mysql_query (or $mysqli->query) returns false in case of error, so you need to check mysql_error() to get error description from the server. From that description you will see what is wrong with your query.

Answer (score 1):

mysql meaning that apa_calda is a column name. if it's a value, quote it like

```
SELECT user_id FROM detalii_contor WHERE tip_contor='apa_calda'
```

about $_POST['util'] - try to use $_REQUEST -
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php

Comment: sorry, different result, same error:
#1054 - Unknown column 'tip_contor' in 'where clause'

Comment: Unknown column? a you sure? please provide you code, where you get $contor

Comment: Unknown column 'tip_contor' - this mean that you type wrong column name

Comment: $contor="apa_calda"; this is how it's defined
tip_contor is correct, i checked, rechecked and checked again, no spaces before or after.

Answer (score 0):

may be you set $contor in function? then you should use directive "global"