# Could not execute SELECT Login_Name FROM memberdirectory WHERE Login_Name = saviobosco (1054)Unknown column 'saviobosco' in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
$username = stripslashes($username); 


// check if usernames exists   


$sql = "SELECT Login_Name FROM memberdirectory WHERE Login_Name = $username";  


if ($result = mysqli_query($pdo,$sql)) {   

    $row = mysqli_num_rows($result);    

    // if yes, fetch the encrypted password
```

Comment: Since you're using `mysqli` you could just use bound parameters to avoid that (and many other) issues.

Comment: ***Warning*** [SQL Injection Attack](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/327:_Exploits_of_a_Mom) ahead. Use prepared statements.

Comment: I'm downvoting, since we don't like code dumped into a question without an introductory paragraph. Please be willing to write an introduction, and not just "See title". Explain what you have tried to fix it, and whether there were any similar problems on the web that might help.

Comment: This is also a duplicate of [1054 - Unknown column 'apa\_calda' in 'where clause'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2930364/1054-unknown-column-apa-calda-in-where-clause) (and several others, see the _Related_ sidebar). All you needed do in this case is search for "SELECT could not execute unknown column MySQL".

Answer (score 2):

You are missing quotes around the string value:

```
$sql = "SELECT Login_Name FROM memberdirectory WHERE Login_Name = '$username'";
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using mysqli, why limit yourself to manually sanitizing your inputs? MysqlI has prepared statements to handle and format your query correctly.

```
$Conn = new mysqli("host","user","pass","database");

$Query = $Conn->prepare("SELECT Login_Name FROM memberdirectory WHERE Login_name=?");
$Query->bind_param('s',$username);
$Query->execute();
$Query->fetch();
$Row_Number = $Query->num_rows;
$Query->close(); // close the connection. Always a benefit and can save you complications later down the line
```

Then validate:

```
if ($Row_Number > 0){

} // Example only.
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$username = stripslashes($username); 
$sql = "SELECT Login_Name FROM memberdirectory WHERE Login_Name =".$username;
if ($result = mysqli_query($pdo,$sql)) {   

    $row = mysqli_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: That would give the same error message, `$username` needs to be within `'...'`.